# How to know which element is being displayed in GWT ScrollPanel

Tags: gwt

A question about GWT ScrollPanel.

Is there any way to determine which child element is being displayed in ScrollPanel?

(Of course, ScrollPanel contains DecoratorPanel that has HTML object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in functionality to do so, not in DOM nor in GWT.

If you have fixed height elements you might try to calculate if certain element is shown: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling)

Comment: Alright. I found similar answer that use jquery. As you mentioned, I cannot find any solution in GWT.

Comment: Try to implement that logic in GWT. jQuery was used only to select the right elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the GWT method that does the Job (it is translated from the JQuery solution suggested above).

```
    /**
 * @param widget the widget to check
 * @return true if the widget is in the visible part of the page
 */
private boolean isScrolledIntoView(Widget widget) {
    if (widget != null) {
        int docViewTop = Window.getScrollTop();
        int docViewBottom = docViewTop + Window.getClientHeight();
        int elemTop = widget.getAbsoluteTop();
        int elemBottom = elemTop + widget.getOffsetHeight();
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a widget is visible in a scroll panel, you can do it in this way (Similar to Massi's solution):

```
  /**
   * @param widget the widget to check
   * @return true if the widget is in the visible part of the scroll panel
   */
  private boolean isVisibleInScrollPanel(Widget widget, ScrollPanel scrollPanel) {
    if (widget != null) {
      int containerTop = scrollPanel.getAbsoluteTop();
      int containerBottom = containerTop + scrollPanel.getOffsetHeight();
      int widgetTop = widget.getAbsoluteTop();
      int widgetBottom = widgetTop + widget.getOffsetHeight();
      return ((widgetBottom <= containerBottom) && (widgetTop >= containerTop));
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I used this method in this way:

```
// When the selected widget is invisible, then we ensure it to be visible
if (!isVisibleInScrollPanel(widget, scrollPanel)) {
  scrollPanel.ensureVisible(widget);
}
```