# GWT Sync panel scrolls or just panel

Tags: gwt

Hi i am trying to develop a GWT web application for teachers. On the one of my page is showing student information. 
Page has *DockLayoutPanel* , on the west side there is a *CellList* and on the center there is flextable

- CellList has content info about studuents (Name , surname , id)
- FlexTable has detailed info about students , on each row there is one widget for one student
- each celllist and flextable is loaded with same data , one is showing short info other detailed.

My question is  flextable is inside of scroll panel , is it posible to select record in the cell list which is displaying on the flextable(scroll panel)
i can get record id from both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution :

- firstly i put scroll handler to my flextables scroll panel
- then i wrote a method for handler that checks which widget is showing in scroll panel ([How to know which element is being displayed in GWT ScrollPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225660/how-to-know-which-element-is-being-displayed-in-gwt-scrollpanel)) btw i have overloaded scrollpanel class that that takes widger and item id

  private class CustomScrollPanel extends ScrollPanel{
   private long id;
   CustomScrollPanel(long id,ScrollPanel sp){
    this.id = id;
    setWidget(sp);
   }
   public long getId(){
    return id;
   }
  }
- Now i have id which is showing on flextable , lastly i wrote a method that checks CellList with ids , when it founds the id in cellists visible items, selects its cell with selection model of celllist